# Как написать один цикл сразу для нескольких полей

Tags: php

Есть несколько полей для картинок.  С каждой после загрузки должно произойти один и тот же цикл. Можно ли как нибудь сразу для все прописать?

Comment: Код для начала покажите.

Comment: >С каждой после загрузки должно произойти один и тот же цикл. Можно ли как нибудь сразу для все прописать?

Сразу для все можно, но только с после загрузки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-> [пользовательские функции в php](http://www.php.su/functions/custom/)